# Notice: Undefined index: body_nohtml in /var/www/series/dynamic/AtomCMS/functions/data.php on line 12

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
    function data_page($dbc,$id)
    {   
       $q = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = $id";
       $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);                               //query                               
       $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);  
       $data['body_nohmtl'] = strip_tags($data['body']);    
       if($data['body'] == $data['body_nohtml'])
       {
          $data['body_formatted'] = '<p>'.$data['body'].'</p>'; 
       }
       else {
           $data['body_formatted'] = $data['body'];
       }    
       return $data;            
    } ?>
```

Comment: bad question, bad formatting.... but there is an typo: body_nohmtl != body_nohtml

Answer (score 1):

You can not stored data like this $data['body_nohmtl'] = strip_tags($data['body']);

that's why you have got an error "Notice: Undefined index: body_nohtml in..."

**You can user this code instead of Old code**

```
$t = strip_tags($data['body']);
if($data['body'] == $t) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if($data['body'] == $data['body_nohtml'])
```

Try to do like this:

```
if(isset($data['body_nohtml']) && $data['body'] == $data['body_nohtml'])
```